# Find $\vec{\nabla} dz$ where $dz=x^3y\:dx+e^{-y}x\:dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is not a homework problem. I was wondering how we might find $\vec{\nabla}\:dz$ if $dz=\left(x^3y\right)\:dx+\left(e^{-y}x\right)\:dy$?

I would think that the partial derivatives would simply cancel the terms opposite, for instance:
\begin{align}
\vec{\nabla}\:dz&=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(x^3y\:dx+e^{-y}x\:dy\right)\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(x^3y\:dx+e^{-y}x\:dy\right)
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
x^3y\\
e^{-y}x
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
but this seems too simple. I know that the total derivative of $z$ would probably take this form, however, so it seems these terms would themselves be the partial derivatives. Any hints/suggestions?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Wrote $\omega$ instead of $dz$, because $dz$ isn't a closed form. $\left| {} \right|$ means determinant. That's what I'm thinking on:

$$\begin{gathered}
  \omega  = {x^3}ydx + {e^{ - y}}xdy \hfill \\
  d\omega  = {x^3}dy \wedge dx + {e^{ - y}}dx \wedge dy = ({e^{ - y}} - {x^3})dx \wedge dy \hfill \\
  \nabla \omega  = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}}&{{x^3}y} \\ 
  {\frac{\partial }{{\partial y}}}&{{e^{ - y}}x} 
\end{array}} \right| = {e^{ - y}} - {x^3} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Comment: In case ${\nabla _X}\omega$ for vectorfield $X$, then for me it's covariant derivative.